# Return null if value does not match after filter

Tags: sql, db2

Does anyone know how to return a row with null if it does not match the join clause after using a where clause?

I have two tables lets call them  A and B.

EXAMPLE:

```
TABLE A                    TABLE B 
COL1  COL2                COL1   COL2  COL3  COL 4         
A       1                 A       1     sd    01/02
B       2                 B       2     aa    01/05
C       3                 C       3     bb    01/07
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A as a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE B as b ON a.COL1 = b.COL1 AND a.COL2 = b.COL2
```

THE result i get is

```
    COL1  COL2    COL1.2   COL2.2  COL3  COL4         
     A       1      A       1     sd    01/02
     B       2      B       2     aa    01/05
     C       3      C       3     bb    01/07
```

Now when i add this where clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A as a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE B as b ON a.COL1 = b.COL1 AND a.COL2 = b.COL2 
WHERE COL4 >= '01/05'
```

I get this:

```
    COL1  COL2    COL1.2   COL2.2  COL3  COL4         
     B       2      B       2      aa    01/05
     C       3      C       3      bb    01/07
```

My question is how can i get the query to display this instead:

```
    COL1  COL2    COL1.2   COL2.2  COL3  COL4         
     A      NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL  NULL
     B       2      B       2      aa    01/05
     C       3      C       3      bb    01/07
```

Any help or ideas will greatly be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use an outer join with a table containing unique values for `COL1`.  You could potentially use a CTE if you have no such table:

```
with categories as (
  select distinct col1
    from a)
select categories.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.col4
  from categories
    left outer join 
        (a join b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and b.col4 >= '01/05')
      on categories.col1 = a.col1
```

The magic is in the nested join. Your original query is provided in that join, but if you need all the missing `COL1` values in addition to those that have a value, you need to join your original query with a list of the valid `COL1` values. So this statement uses a common table expression (CTE), that is the `with` clause, and joins it using a left outer join with your original query, that is the nested join.

Additional note, `OUTER` is not necessary as it is implied when join type `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, or `FULL` is specified, I just like to be explicit with that.

Comment: You NAILED IT! Thank you so much. Could you briefly explain the concept of the syntax or guide me with what to search for on google to better understand why it worked?

Comment: Do you understand the nested join?

Comment: my understanding is that the         (a join b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and b.col4 >= '01/05')
      on categories.col1 = a.col1) firsts joins the two tables together with all the criteria  which then tries to match with the distinct column in the table used for the outer join. Is that correct? (btw i used the CTE method)

Comment: Close. (a join b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and b.col4 >= '01/05') joins the two table to gether using the criteria. Then categories left outer join (...) on categories.col1 = a.col1 joins the results of the nested join to the CTE with an outer join.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a strange request? May I ask why you want to return the rows as NULL when your where clause explicitly states to exclude the NULL values? I can help you find a better way if you can provide some more detail.

Comment: the company i work for would like to see that the identifier provided from their list is represented on the results. so after filtering the different columns out and no matches are found with that criteria, they would like to see just a single line stating null. Does that make sense? Strange request indeed!!

Comment: I see - @jmarkmurphy solution above is a good one and should provide you with what you need.  Let me know if that does it for you!

Comment: @jmarkmurphy solution did indeed work. Thank you for the help. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just move the condition to the `on` clause.  It is on the second table in the `left join`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A a LEFT JOIN
     TABLE B b
     ON a.COL1 = b.COL1 AND a.COL2 = b.COL2 and b.COL4 >= '01/05';
```

Comment: Tried this and it gave me the same results from my original question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is actually slightly different from the results in the original question. The`WHERE` in the the original is replaced by `AND` which has the effect of bringing the where criteria into the join criteria. It should produce something similar to your expected results except that all columns from `A` will be non null, and you could get multiple rows where `COL1 = 'A'` as long as there are multiple rows where `COL1 = 'A'`.